# Query embedded collection in a sails project with mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sails.js, node-mongodb-native, sails-mongo

I'm using sails-mongo in my project and i need to execute one query in an embedded collection.
My data are something like the following:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53906c6254f36df504e99b8f"),
    "title"    : "my post"
    "comments" : [ 
        {
            "author" : "foo",
            "comment" : "foo comment"
        },
        {
            "author" : "bar",
            "comment" : "bar comment"
        }        
    ],
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2014-06-05T13:10:58.365Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2014-06-05T13:10:58.365Z")
}
```

for example, i need to extract the `comments` of author `foo`.
Apparently sails does not support this feature yet, so i was considering using the object `db` of [mongodb-native](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native) to make this kind of query.
As sails-mongo uses mongodb-native, can i have access to db object in my sails project? Or i will need build a new connection using mongodb-native?
If anyone has a better idea I'd be grateful. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you need to do is *access* the embedded comments, Waterline should work fine.  Just do a normal `find` or `findOne`, and the comments should be accessible on the returned objects.

If you need to *query* the comments, e.g. to find Posts with comments by a certain author, you can access the underlying `mongodb-native` collection using the `.native()` method of your Sails model class:

```
Post.native(function(err, collection) {
    if (err) { 
        // handle error getting mongo collection
    }
    collection.find({'comments.author':'foo'}).toArray(function(err, results) {
        // Do something with results
    });
});
```